# How to transform QuerySet to another type?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Say you've got these models:

```py
class NetworkMember(models.Model):
    network = models.ForeignKey(Network, related_name='members', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='network_id_id')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='user_id_id')

class Network(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

And you have filtered `NetworkMember`:

```py
    user_networks = NetworkMember.objects.filter(user=self.user)
```

Now `user_networks` is QuerySet of `NetworkMember`, how can I transform it to QuerySet of `Network`?

Doing `.values('network')` and `.values_list('network')` doesn't change the type of QuerySet to `Network`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Network.objects.filter(members__user=self.user)
```

One can use double underscores (`__`) to look "through" relations. Since you specified the `related_name='members'`, we access the relation in reverse.

If there are multiple `NetworkMember`s with the same user to the same `Network`, then that `Network` will be returned that many times as there are such `NetworkMember`'s, you can use [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to prevent that:

```
Network.objects.filter(members__user=self.user).distinct()
```